# Finding Duplicates in an unsorted array with different values in O(n) Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm

I've had this question in a data structures course, essentially I was given two different arrays with the same size of N, the only thing we know about the values inside those arrays is that they're entirely different other than those two integers we are looking for. I thought about merging them into a singular array, keeping it still O(n) in terms of time complexity. My question is: can I find those duplicates somehow while still keeping the O(n) time complexity? I feel like sorting this is a naive approach which will take the complexity up to O(nlogn). Thanks in advance!

I thought maybe using the pivot algorithm might work, however in hindsight it won't reduce my worst case time complexity. Is there a way to solve this some other way?

Comment: Create a set from the first array, and iterate the second array to filter for values that are in set?

Comment: Further to @trincot's comment, adding an element to a set and determining if a set contains a particular element (similar to adding a key to a hash or finding if a hash has a particular key) is "almost" constant-time, O(1), so the procedure described is almost, and for practical purposes, equal to, O(n).